# how can i create before pseudo-element under my button element?

Tags: html, css, z-index

### HTML

```
<button>Get Postion</button>
```

### CSS

```
button {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: red;
    color: wheat;
    border: 4px solid yellowgreen;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    left: -4px;
    height: calc(100% + 8px);
    width: calc(100% + 8px);
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

---

how can i fix this?  z-index is not working and before element takes button borders

[button looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYGaJ.png)

Comment: Include what you want your end result to look like

Comment: you can comment the ```z-index: 1``` in the ```button {} ```, if this doesnt resolves your query can you print what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

`button::before` is what happens at the start of the animation
`button::after` is what happen at the end of the animation
`button` is what your static button looks like.

Try adding a `button::after` to see if it works.

Comment: thats not working

Comment: What did you put into button after?